# Is there any problems when using Delphi to create Web-Service client?

Tags: web-services, delphi, delphi-xe

I plan to start developing web-service client using Delphi XE. It looks like creating web-service client on delphi is easy to do.

Is there any bugs or problems when creating WebService on Delphi XE? 
Is there any problems with other versions of Delphi (not XE) ?

(To create web-service i plan using WSDL-importer dialog)

Please, place Delphi version, you used to create web-service in answer.

Comment: from what I know there aren't 'generic known problems'...

Comment: This is not a real question. It's way to vague and subject to interpretation. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created several webservice-clients in Delphi, all by using the wsdl. I have not encountered any problems so far. I have encountered some small problems, but nothin that couldn't be resolved with Google or Stackoverflow :-)

Comment: What version of Delphi did you use?

Answer (score 2):

It depends. To answer your last question first, later versions of Delphi are better at generating a Web service client than earlier versions.

As for your first question. I have also created a number of Web service clients (and servers) using various versions of Delphi (most recently, Delphi 2007 and Delphi XE, though I also used Delphi 6, Delphi 7, and Delphi 2005). When the Web service methods use simple data types in its method parameters and return values (strings and integers), Delphi often does a good job of generating the client code using the WSDL importer. When complex data types are involved (objects, for example), it might be more challanging. For example, if the Web service uses complex types, and the WSDL is the only source of information about those types (you did not create the Web service, there is no documentation, or you cannot get the source code to it), it might take more work. It really depends on how complex the complex type is.

Additionally, if the Web service employs additional features such as authentication or other specialized headers, you will have to manually modify the code created by the WSDL importer. However, as birger noted, most of these issues can be resolved with research.

On the other hand, if the Web service was created in Delphi, it is usually very easy to create the Web service client.